# regex to replace a whole word, not characters

Tags: java, regex

i have the following snippet:

```
String[] alsoReplace = {"and", "the", "&"};
    for (String str : alsoReplace) {
        s = s.replaceAll("(?i)" + str + "(\\s+)?" , "");
    }
```

I need to alter the regex in it, so as to replace the "and" or "the" found in a string as a word, not as just part of a word.

example:

Dean and James -> Dean James

Deand James -> Deand James

I also need to keep the case insensitive replacement,

how this line should become?

```
        s = s.replaceAll("(?i)" + str + "(\\s+)?" , "");
```

Comment: Can't you use `string.replace(" and ", " ");` ? Or with your array `string.replace(" " + str + " ", " ");`

Comment: @PhilippeB. What about replace word is the last one where no space after that.

Comment: That is right ! Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\b`(word boundary) to replace the whole word only and after replace all multiple spaces with a single space.

```
String s = "Deand  and  James And";
String[] alsoReplace = {"and", "the", "&"};
for (String str : alsoReplace) {
    s = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b" + str + "\\b" , "");
}
s = s.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "); // remove multiple space into single
```

Output: `Deand James`

Comment: i had tried with the following: s = s.replaceAll("\\b(?i)\\b" i do not know why this is wrong

Comment: Did you put replace word in regex?

Comment: no worries, i will use your suggestion,just was wondering, why the "\\b(?i)\\b" iw wtrong, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first part is quite easy: You don't want to replace "and" with "" but rather " and " (a full word defined by being surrounded with spaces) with " ", so something similar to

```
String[] alsoReplace = {" and ", " the ", "&"};
for (String str : alsoReplace) {
  s = s.replaceAll("(?i)" + str + "(\\s+)?" , " ");
}
```